# defining a loop in a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have contstructed a 3d numpy matrice of zeros then normalized the rows. Now I want to loop
trough the matrice and add +1 for each time one item  follows another item in the nested list:

```
nested list = [(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)][(0,5),(1,6),(2,7)]
```

I want to loop trough the nested list so that the last index of each `tupleindex [1]` gets `+1` when following from another tuple with `index [1]`, for instance if `index [1]` in `tuple (2,2),2`, is following from `index[1]` in `(1,1), 1`, the matrice column gets `+1` matrice - the matrice 3*3 of zeros and then normalized `row/=row.sum()`

I've tried the following:

```
 try:
        for i in data:
            for j in i:
               for k in range(len(j)):
                    matrice [ i[j[k]][1], i[j[k]+1][1] ] += 1

  except(IndexError):
            pass
  return matrice
```

which gives the following results:

```
[ 0    2    0] [ 0   0    2] [ 0   2    0]
```

although the       results should be

```
[ 0    2    0][ 0   0    2] [ 2   0   0]]
```

2 in the last row should be on this index and not in the middle

That makes me think there is something with the loop `a [ i[j[k]][1], i[j[k]+1][1] ] += 1`. I've tried a `[ i[j[k]][1]**+=1**, i[j[k]+1][1] ] += 1` adding +1 but this doesn't do the work. Any help is greatly appriciated

Comment: What is `data` in your sample code?  Also, you say you constructed a *3d* matrix, but your sample code and output appear to show the use of a 2d matrix.  What is the shape of `matrice`?

Comment: Hi Warren, data is a tupled list [(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)] and the matrice is 3*3 of zeros. I plotted it as a line, first row first. Is the index of [ i[j[k]][1], i[j[k]+1][1] ] that suggests a 2 d array, and how do I then change it to a third index, like if I want to get index y in range k,would I have to do something like i[j[k[y]]]?

Comment: @user1749431 Please, improve the details about data and matrice. The nested list defined above does not participate in your attempt?